# Vim autocommand not triggering on search?

Tags: vim, automation, indentation

I use Vim 7.3, and have this in my `.vimrc` (and nothing else):

```
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType java :setlocal sw=4 ts=4 sts=2 noet
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost ~/testdir/* setlocal sw=2 ts=2 sts=2 et
```

I have a directory `~/testdir` which only contains a subdirectory `p` and the file `~/testdir/p/A.java` which contains this:

```
class A {
}
```

If I open `A.java` by saying `:e ~/testdir/p/A.java` then `:set et?` reports that `expandtab` is currently **ON**.

On the other hand, if I start a new instance of Vim and go `:vim A ~/testdir/**` then this search will open `A.java`, but now `:set et?` tells me `expandtab` is **OFF**.

How do I make my intended indentation settings always apply for files under `~/testdir/`?

Comment: is the file `X` located under `$HOME/git/repo/` ?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question to clarify this!

Comment: Don't know, but there's a note for BufReadPost in the help saying 'does NOT work for ":r file"'. Perhaps it doesn't work for `:vim` neither.

Comment: @glts doing a quick test with the autocmd `:autocmd BufReadPost * echo 'BufReadPost'` and then doing `:vim /abc/ **` you get quite a few messages logged to the screen. So I think it works for `:vim`

Comment: Maybe this conflicts with my filetype plugins somehow...

I'm trying to distill a SSCCE now, but it's difficult. Seems to work for some filetypes but not others.

Comment: @user11171 Any comments on my answer?

Comment: I have edited the description so that it now describes a reproducible example of my problem. Sorry for the long delay. I have not been able to resolve it yet, and it's slowly driving me mad.

Comment: This is a very different question than the one you originally asked.

Comment: My original question was "Why are these settings not applied", I do not see how the question is now different other than the example which exposes the undesired effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event `BufReadPost` should be being fired. Check that writing a message. This is:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost $HOME/git/repo/* echom "Reading buffer " . expand("<afile>")
```

Look for the messages with:

```
:messages
```

If the messages are there, then you know you are setting those options for the buffer. So, if the options have changed when the buffer is displayed, perhaps a plugin is setting them to some other thing. Check who is the culprit by showing who last changed the option with

```
:verbose set sw?
```

If that doesn't lead you to a solution, try using `BufWinEnter` instead of `BufReadPost`. That would probably work.

Comment: I have narrowed it down now to the problem being caused by a filetype plugin. The `BufReadPost` does trigger, but I guess the filetype plugin runs after that and overrides my settings.

Comment: Just tried with `BufWinEnter` and that seems to work, I don't think I tried this when I first read your answer but this seems to have solved my problem! Thanks!

After reading the docs a bit it seems like `BufEnter` could also work.

Answer (score 1):

Vim explicitly recommends using `~` for the user home.

The help at [`:h autocmd-patterns`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-patterns) says that you can use environment variables in the event patterns ...

> ... [a]nd `~` can be used for the home directory (if `$HOME` is defined):
>
> ```
> :autocmd BufWritePost ~/.vimrc   so ~/.vimrc
> :autocmd BufRead ~archive/*      set readonly
> ```
>
> The environment variable is expanded when the autocommand is defined, not when
>   the autocommand is executed.  This is different from the command!

So, change `$HOME` to `~` in your autocommand.

Even if your problem turns out to be unrelated it's good to follow the practice recommended in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The autocmd does work but probably not the way you expect since you did not set `softtabstop`.

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost ~/git/repo/* setlocal sw=2 ts=2 sts=2 et
```

If you do not set softtabstop it will keep its old value. If this value is not 0 (which seems to be the case) when you press tab you will get the number of softtabstop spaces inserted into the file. And it will look like its not working.

It is generally a good idea to set shiftwidth, tabstop, and softtabstop to the same value if you ever change it.

Its also probably a good idea to make the set command local to the buffer by using setlocal.

Take a look at `:h softtabstop`

---

You can see that the autocmd "works" when softtabstop is set to its default value (of 0) if you run the command like this. And then run your `:vim` command

```
vim -u NONE -N -c'autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost $HOME/git/repo/* set sw=2 ts=2 et'
```

Comment: I am setting `softtabstop` now too, but with no luck.